# Find the Automorphism group of a Brandt semigroup $B(G,2)$ ,where $G $ is a cyclic group of order 4.

Tags: semigroups, group-homomorphism

> Find the Automorphism group of a Brandt semigroup $B(G,2)$ ,where $G $ is a cyclic group of order 4.

Take $G=\{ e, a ,a^2, a^3\}$

$B(G,2) = \{ (i,a^s , j) : 1 \leq i,j \leq 2  \ \  , 0\leq s  \leq 3 \} \cup \{0\}$ and the binary operation is defind by
$$(i, a^r , j) (k,a^s , l)  = \begin{cases} (i,a^ra^s,l) & \text{if }  \ \ j=k \\
0 &\text{if } otherwise \end{cases}$$

What is the Automorphism group of $B(G,2)$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I  do  not have any idea how to start , Please give me any hint